# How to set minimum axis values in Excel 2007 based on cell value?

Tags: excel, excel-charts

Is it possible to set minimum axis values in Excel 2007 based on cell value? For example, I would like to put a value into a cell and match the beginning point X Axes chart's to that value without Macro.

Any help would be appreciated.. thank you!

Comment: Could you perhaps give an example of what you have, and what you would like it to look like?

Comment: May be it's possible, may be not! What have you done so far? Can you rephrase your question with more details, specially at this: "value into a cell and match the beginning point of X". Otherwise community either vote it for closing: `1`. Not clear what you are asking `2`. Too broad

Comment: [This is my chart](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XW-fqYcp_Sw/VZy7xCgxPSI/AAAAAAAAAb4/EWEj2kfejFs/w426-h313/6-30-2015%2B3.57.44%2BAM.png) 
For an example I have a Chart with minimum value/beginning point of X Axes : 48. Then I want to change the minimum value, normally way : 1. right click  horizontal(X) axes 2. Choose format Axis.. 3. set minimum  and close.
But I want the minimum value automatically changed when I set the value of cell A1. When I set cell A1= 40, minimum value X axis will automatic become 40 too.